# Why I have so many veth interfaces in firewalld Zone

Tags: centos, docker, firewalld, veth

I have a server that runs `docker` and `firewalld`, everything works fine but I **cannot** reload `firewalld` with the command

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

One thing that I notice is in the result of this command

```
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0 veth0008eb7 veth00197d0 veth0023d4b ...(10K of these)... veth036eaae
```

I have over 10K of `veth.....` interfaces, that's insane.

- I try to run a script to delete all of these interfaces but was not able to reload.
- Each time I reload `firewall-cmd --reload`, the server is unable to connect

How do I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to fix this by restart `firewalld`, everything is okay now. Does anyone know the root cause of this issue?